# StackOverflowError al llamar el método toString en un par de objetos mapeado en Hibernate (M:N)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lombok

Tengo un inconveniente al mandar a llamar el método toString para ver los valores en consola.

Tengo un mapeo de M:N entre las entidades Servicio y Sucursal. Y un controlador donde son utilizadas, a continuación muestro fragmentos de código:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Servicio {
    
    ....
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "folio_fk")
    private Sucursal sucursal;

    ...

    public Sucursal getSucursal() {
        return sucursal;
    }

    public void setSucursal(Sucursal sucursal) {
        this.sucursal = sucursal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Servicio [id=" + id + ", tipoServicio=" + tipoServicio + ", categoria=" + categoria + ", descripcion="
                + descripcion + ", inicioInstalacion=" + inicioInstalacion + ", costo=" + costo + ", finInstalacion="
                + finInstalacion + ", sucursal=" + sucursal + "]";
    }
    
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Sucursal {
    
    ...
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sucursal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Servicio> servicios; 
    
    ...

    public List<Servicio> getServicios() {
        return servicios;
    }

    public void setServicios(List<Servicio> servicios) {
        this.servicios = servicios;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sucursal [folio=" + folio + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", calle=" + calle + ", numero=" + numero
                + ", colonia=" + colonia + ", codigoPostal=" + codigoPostal + ", alcaldia=" + alcaldia + ", contacto="
                + contacto + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", correo=" + correo + ", servicios=" + servicios + "]";
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/servicios")
public class ServicioController {

...

@GetMapping(value = "/tablaServicios")
    public String mostrarTablaServicios(Model model) {
        logger.debug("******** Entrando al metodo mostrarTablaServicios ********");
        List<Servicio> servicios = servicioService.obtenerTodosLosServicios();
        model.addAttribute("servicios", servicios);
        logger.debug("Servicios: " + servicios);
        return "listaServicios";
    }
    
...

}
```

En donde ambas clases que se mapean tengo sobrescrito el método toString.
Sin embargo, ha la hora de entrar en el controlador y mostrarlo en la consola mediante un logger, me genera un desborde de memoria.

Error marcado en consola:

```
...
2023-04-26 22:32:46.067 ERROR 17344 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at com.uacm.aktivai.model.Servicio.toString(Servicio.java:116) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4218) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
        at com.uacm.aktivai.model.Sucursal.toString(Sucursal.java:152) ~[classes/:na]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final
...
```

Como sulución temporal, estoy comentando la línea del logger y funciona renderizando y mostrando información de manera correcta. Sin embargo me gustaría saber el porque del error anterior y cómo podría evitarlo de ser posible sin quitar, o comentar la línea del logger.

Comment: por eso no debes usar @Data, agrega cada anotación individual y veras cual es el problema. Si aun despues de eso no lo decifras no dudes en escribir

Comment: Hola Dissek, podrías mostrarnos donde invocas a los métodos **toString**, gracias.

Comment: Saludos. No use mucho Java; pero tu código indica que cada `Servicio` tiene `Sucursal` y a su vez `Sucursal` tiene varios `Servicio`; creo ahí se genera el error; prueba convirtiendo el primer elemento `List<Servicio> servicios = servicioService.obtenerTodosLosServicios();` a `String` haber si falla. De ser así es lo anidado de la clase dentro de clase.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Sí, no es indispensable esa anotación ya que estoy declarando los getters y setters de manera explicita, se me pasó eliminarla, una disculpa.

Comment: @MarcePuente se invoca de manera implísita en el controlador, podríamos ser explícitos y escribir  (logger.debug("Servicios: " + servicios.toString());).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El desborde de memoria se da por recursión mutua en los métodos `toString` de las clases `Sucursal` y `Servicio`. El método `toString` de `Sucursal` está definido en función del `toString` de `Servicio` y viceversa. Esto genera un encadenamiento de llamadas hasta llenar la memoria disponible.

La forma de solucionar esto es rompiendo la recursión, para lo cual hay que eliminar esta dependencia mutua haciendo que los `toString` no estén definidos uno en función del otro.

Por ejemplo en `Servicio` podemos eliminar la referencia a `Sucursal` de esta forma:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Servicio [id=" + id + ", tipoServicio=" + tipoServicio + ", categoria=" + categoria + ", descripcion="
                + descripcion + ", inicioInstalacion=" + inicioInstalacion + ", costo=" + costo + ", finInstalacion="
                + finInstalacion + "]";
    }
```

o bien recuperando alguna propiedad de la sucursal, pero no la lista de servicios. Por ejemplo:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Servicio [id=" + id + ", tipoServicio=" + tipoServicio + ", categoria=" + categoria + ", descripcion="
                + descripcion + ", inicioInstalacion=" + inicioInstalacion + ", costo=" + costo + ", finInstalacion="
                + finInstalacion + ", sucursal=" + sucursal.getNombre() + "]";
    } // estoy suponiendo que la sucursal tiene una propiedad nombre
```